# How to get Friends UniqID with Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

here is my Friends Table in Sql 
[image]

i need a Query to give me all friends's IDs of a user, i wrote this query but it selects all rows not all IDs

```
    SELECT * from Friend_Table
 where (SenderID=@ID and ReqStatus='True')
  or
    ReciverID=@ID and ReqStatus='True')
```

my problem is a user ID can be in senderID or reciverID and i need only one column in returning table !

MY output table like :

[image]

Comment: show us Your Expected Output table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose the opposite ID in the select clause. You could either union 2 queries together, or use a case statement to pick:

(note, untested code)

```
select
    case when SenderID=@ID then ReciverID else SenderID end as OtherPersonID
from
    Friend_Table
where
    ReqStatus='True'
    and (SenderID=@ID or ReciverID=@ID)
```

As a union:

```
select ReciverID as OtherPersonID from Friend_Table where (ReqStatus='True' and SenderID=@ID)
union
select SenderID as OtherPersonID from Friend_Table where (ReqStatus='True' and ReciverID=@ID)
```

Also, the correct spelling is actually 'Receiver'.